# Best journal mode for a single writer

Tags: database, sqlite, sqlite-journal-mode

I'm using sqlite3 for a logging function. If I don't need any concurrency (there's only one writer all the time), but I need fast inserts what journal mode should I choose?

Comment: If there's only one connection ever trying to write, and nothing trying to read from the database, probably TRUNCATE if it's doing a lot of writing. If on a regular basis other connections are trying to read at the same time the writer is doing its thing, WAL.

Answer (score 0):

WAL mode needs less synchronization, so [writes are faster](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#performance_considerations), except when the database decides to do a [checkpoint](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#ckpt).